# HTTPS communication with web service from phoneGap

Tags: android, ios, https, cordova

I am developing phoneGap application which is integrated with web service for requesting data.

Communication used to happen through `HTTP` but I want to take it to `HTTPS` communication.

I integrated SSL for my tomcat server and I can send `HTTPS` request from `RESTClient` using browser.

But my phoneGap mobile application is not able to communicate for `HTTPS` request.

Any extra setting required for it?

I am targeting android and iOS for now.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We had to face the same issue last week in our own project.
In Android we didn't have any problem with it, we observed that Android trusted all the certificates (are you having issues with Android?), however in iOS we had some trouble.

The first thing you can do is to install the trusted certificate in your iOS... but it will be problematic for basic users.

The solution we decided to take was to allow access to all SSL for our application, in order to do that you have to add the next code at the end of your AppDelegate.m file:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
     return YES; 
}
@end
```